# Trouble attaching postgres database to Heroku application

Tags: django, database, postgresql, heroku

I have a Django application with PostgresQL database. I have successfully deployed the application on heroku (myapp), but getting trouble attaching the local database to it.

To attach the local database to my Heroku application (myapp), I followed these steps

1.Created database (db-name) dump file

```
sudo pg_dump -U postgres db-name > db-name.dump
```

2.Uploaded dump file online where its accessible through link

```
https:url/db-name.dump
```

on following the above link db-name.dump file gets downloaded

3.Used pg:backups:restore command to restore the backup on my heroku application

```
heroku pg:backups:restore 'https:url/db-name.dump' DATABASE_URL --confirm myapp
```

On issuing the above pg:backups:restore command, I am getting an error

```
Restoring... !
 ▸    An error occurred and the backup did not finish.
 ▸    
 ▸    waiting for restore to complete
 ▸    pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header
 ▸    pg_restore finished with errors
 ▸    waiting for download to complete
 ▸    download finished successfully
 ▸    
 ▸    Run heroku pg:backups:info r004 for more details.
```

Any guessed whats going on here..

Comment: I expect you are supposed to replace DATABASE_URL with your actual database URL.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I already tried that got this error `Unknown database: 'postgres://dburl' Valid options are: DATABASE_URL`

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? It's driving me crazy